# Apache geode multiple regions disk store

Tags: geode

if I have 10 or 15 geode regions, and I want to persist 5 regions, can I use 1 disk store for all the regions?

```
<region name="region1" refid="REPLICATE_PERSISTENT"><region-attributes disk-store-name="regionStore" disk-synchronous="false"></region-attributes></region>
<region name="region2" refid="REPLICATE/>
<region name="region3" refid="REPLICATE/>
<region name="region4" refid="REPLICATE_PERSISTENT"><region-attributes disk-store-name="regionStore" disk-synchronous="false"></region-attributes></region>
<region name="region5" refid="REPLICATE_PERSISTENT"><region-attributes disk-store-name="regionStore" disk-synchronous="false"></region-attributes></region>
```

Then the disk store config is

```
<disk-store name="regionStore" compaction-threshold="40" 
    auto-compact="false" allow-force-compaction="true"
    max-oplog-size="512" queue-size="10000"  
    time-interval="15" write-buffer-size="65536"
    disk-usage-warning-percentage="80"
    disk-usage-critical-percentage="98">
   <disk-dirs>
       <disk-dir>C:\DiskStores\regionStore</disk-dir>
   </disk-dirs>
</disk-store>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same `disk-store` can be shared among several regions, yes. It's a best practice, though, to have one `disk-store` per region.